# How to persist data in react on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react component in which I need to persist data when the I refresh page. What should the solution for it? Please help

Comment: try with localStorage

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow can you please elaborate some more on what your exact needs are? you can use browser storage like indexDB or localStorage as @DamianPeralta mentioned but you can also use various other services like AWS, Firebase etc so please elaborate on your needs thanks

Comment: please add some code examples and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sessionStorage or localStorage for it. Store whatever data you want to persist in storage. When you refresh the page get that data from storage in your constructor or  componentWillMount (UNSAFE).

Take a look at this article for info https://medium.com/bother7-blog/localstorage-and-you-2660342a60cb

Comment: NB: `componentWillMount` is deprecated and will soon be removed from React.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the npm package redux-persist or react-persist https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist