# How to retain search terms in input field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, solr

I have an input element,

```js
<div>
  <input type="text" id="query" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

that triggers an `Apache Solr` search. Upon submission the input field is cleared (possibly due to a page reload?).

How can I retain the query terms in the input field (or repopulate it, upon submission)?

Comment: *possibly due to an asynchronous*, No. Async function will not have impact on DOM elements. Is the input part of form? Does the page refreshes upon submit?

Comment: Just look at the Fav icon on browser. Or check network tab. If it refreshes, there would be signs. To persist data through refresh, refer this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542257/how-to-persist-data-in-react-on-page-refresh

Comment: Firefox Developer Tools > Network > HTML panel: a hard reload triggers a 200 request / response; the Solr query triggers no further activity in that panel, so I'm presuming the search requests are *not* reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the button associated with your page issues a submit (e.g. `<button type="submit">Search</button>`). If that is your case, you'll need to make sure you put the value the user submitted when you render the page again, you'll do this in the `value` attribute, e.g.

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="query" autocomplete="off" value="the-value-the-user-entered" />
</div>
```

You could also issue an AJAX call when the user issues the search, in which case, the form won't reload and you won't need to worry about this, but then you will need to write the code to issue the AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. There's no button though; the input value(s) are picked up by Ajax scripts (MVC) model ... and passed to Solr.

Comment: If you are already doing the call to Solr via Ajax then I would guess that JavaScript is reloading the page which will reset the value.